# Should I include fillets on my 3d printed parts?

Tags: 3d-models

A fillet is like a rounded corner but on the inside of the corner.

[image]

Does it make a difference (structurally) to use fillets on a 3d printed part?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your part needs structural support, then the word is: **absolutely**. Fillets provide the added support when you need it. If your part has a meeting line which is sharp - 90° (or perpendicular), there is a natural [stress riser](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/18183/4152) in your design. This is a weak spot where a crack can form. If strength is needed and the fillet won't interfere with the design, it's definitely something you should include with your part.

Comment: Chamfers (flat corner cuts) are a better option for printability, unless the corner is in the XY plane.

Comment: @Trish - chamfers are not really any more printable than a fillet In my (admittedly limited) experiance, and they still leave two stress points.

Comment: Please check out [Makers Muse on fillets & chamfers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTvBOGgx48I).

Comment: @SiHa Fillets are less printable than chamfers (depending on the printing plane), please read [this answer](/a/10278).

Answer (score 11):

Fillets in X-Y plane (i.e. between two vertical surfaces) work great for 3D prints and increase the strength a lot. They usually also improve the print quality, because the print head can keep a constant speed in the curve instead of slowing down to a sharp corner.

However fillets that extend in Z direction (i.e. between a vertical and a horizontal surface) suffer from layer artifacts. Sometimes they can look worse than a sharp corner would. While they do still increase the strength significantly, they are not as strong as similarly sized fillets in X-Y plane are.

Comment: So the nozzle can keep it's speed around corners better, and X-Y fillets are better than Z fillets. Kewlio.